# How to connect raspberry pi to android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi

I was trying to connect my raspberry pi 3 b+ to **android studio**, NOT Android Things. I know that Android Things is more easier but I am currently doing my project so I want to design an interface in android studio.
Does anyone knows how to connect raspberry pi to Android studio? By the way I am using "firebase" as  my database.
Hence whenever I tried to "OFF" my LED via button in Android Apps, firebase will change the status accordingly.

I do search online alot but all the info I collected is how to make connection between Android Things and Raspberry PI. What I need is **raspberry pi+firebase+android studio**

Comment: which OS you are currently using in Raspberry pi?

Comment: @MustafaBohra Raspbian

Comment: have you tried to connect using IP address of your raspberry pi to android studio using adb connect?

Comment: Nope.. Do you have any link/source so that i can refer?

Comment: first you have to get IP of your Raspberry pi, thn connect in Android Studio Terminal using adb connect <IP-ADDRESS>

Comment: @MustafaBohra i got the ip address ady, next step?

Comment: both your raspberry pi and machine must be on same network

Comment: adb connect 192.168.1.1  like this